# Regular Expression issue fitting a output

Tags: python, regex

i'm using Debian Squeeze as NAS_OS and cant install MKVToolnix to use this script

so im trying to just fit the re.compile suite the old mkvtoolnix output.

i was wondering howto fit this command

```
AUDIO_RE    = re.compile(r"Spur ID (\d+): audio \([A-Z0-9_/]+\) [number:\d+ uid:\d+ codec_id:[A-Z0-9_/]+ codec_private_length:\d+ language:([a-z]{3})")
SUBTITLE_RE = re.compile(r"Spur ID (\d+): subtitles \([A-Z0-9_/]+\) [number:\d+ uid:\d+ codec_id:[A-Z0-9_/]+ codec_private_length:\d+ language:([a-z]{3})(?: track_name:\w*)? default_track:[01]{1} forced_track:([01]{1})")
```

to that line type of output ?

```
Track ID 2: audio (A_AC3) [language:ger default_track:1 forced_track:1]
Track ID 3: audio (A_DTS) [language:eng default_track:0 forced_track:0]
Track ID 4: subtitles (S_TEXT/UTF8) [language:eng default_track:0 forced_track:0]
```

this is how far i got - but the script still does not want to work for me

```
AUDIO_RE = re.compile(r"Track ID (\d+): audio \([A-Z0-9_/]+\) [language:[a-z]{3} default_track:[01]{1} forced_track:[01]{1}")
SUBTITLE_RE = re.compile(r"Track ID (\d+): subtitles \([A-Z0-9_/]+\) [language:[a-z]{3} default_track:[01]{1} forced_track:[01]{1}")
```

Script what i'm talking about is here

Comment: You don't need `{1}` -- without a modifier, everything just matches one time.

Comment: You've got some `[` symbols you forgot to escape.

Comment: Still doesnt work                                                                      AUDIO_RE = re.compile(r"Track ID (\d+): audio \([A-Z0-9_/]+\) [language:[a-z]{3} default_track:[01] forced_track:[01]]")
SUBTITLE_RE = re.compile(r"Track ID (\d+): subtitles \([A-Z0-9_/]+\) [language:[a-z]{3} default_track:[01] forced_track:[01]]")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match the audio line (assuming all you want to capture is the track ID):

```
Track ID (\d+): audio \([A-Z0-9_/]+\) \[language:[a-z]{3} default_track:[01] forced_track:[01]\]
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/pZ6aR5

To match the subtitle line (again, same assumption):

```
Track ID (\d+): subtitles \([A-Z0-9_/]+\) \[language:[a-z]{3} default_track:[01] forced_track:[01]\]
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/qO1zV0

Note in both cases the escaped `\[` and `\]`, which are required for matching literal square brackets.

Comment: gonna try in couple minutes. but actually i need language.

Comment: Then just wrap the `[a-z]{3}` in brackets -> `([a-z]{3})`